# How can I export my quiz results to a csv file using python 3?

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I want the results to be in the format Date, Question, Name and Score

```
file = open("results.csv", "a")
file.write('Date, Question, Name, Score\n' + date + ',' question + ',' + name + ',' + score + '\n')
file.close()
```

When I run this code i keep getting the error: TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cast to any ints to string string before you can concat it to another and write to file.

```
str(score) #  <-

 file.write('Date, Question, Name, Score\n' + date + ',' question + ',' + name + ',' + str(score) + '\n')
```

Or use str.format:

```
with open("results.csv", "a") as f: # with closes your files automatically
    f.write('Date, Question, Name, Score\n {}, {}, {}, {}'.format(date, question, name ,score))
```

You may also find the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) useful

Comment: @JD245, no worries, add a link to the  csv module that you may find useful

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: @JD245, there is a nice easy to follow  tut here http://pymotw.com/2/csv/

Answer (score 1):

Then convert it *explicitly* to str:

```
file.write('Date, Question, Name, Score\n' + str(date) + ',' question + ',' + name + ',' + str(score) + '\n')
```